# What type of dash is in “Bo01 - City of Tomorrow”?

Tags: punctuation, hyphens, em-dash

Is the short line in “Bo01 - City of Tomorrow” supposed to be a hyphen, en dash, or em dash?

Also, is the line following "2001" used correctly?

> Malmö has long been renowned as a pioneer in eco-friendly living, so its latest innovation should perhaps come as no surprise. The city’s eco-drive is epitomized by “Bo01 **-** City of Tomorrow” — a project launched in 2001 **—** that has transformed a polluted, defunct shipyard in the city into a green, sustainable living district.

[Source](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/sexy-trash-cans-malmo-sweden-rubbish-intl-scli/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

> An **em-dash** is typically used as a stand-in for a comma or parenthesis to separate out phrases—or even just a word—in a sentence for various reasons.
>
> An **en-dash** is used to connect values in a range or that are related.
>
> A **hyphen** is used to join words in a compound construction, or separate syllables of a word, like during a line break, or (self-evidently) a hyphenated name.

[Source - ELU - When should I use an em-dash, en-dash and hyphen](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen)

So in this case, it is an **em-dash**.

And yes the second **hyphen** is used correctly, the "project launched in 2001" being the “Bo01 - City of Tomorrow”.

Comment: But if we remove "— a project launched in 2001 —" from the OP sentence, something seems wrong:

Comment: It seems wrong but it is grammatically correct @Apollyon

Comment: But that would produce a sentence where the proper name  “Bo01 - City of Tomorrow” is modified by the restrictive clause "that has transformed a polluted, defunct shipyard..."

Comment: Normally, proper names are modified by non-restrictive relative clauses.

Comment: My bad it is a hyphen @Apollyon - caught me on that one :P

Comment: Why do you call the symbol after "2001" a hyphen? It is clearly the second of a pair of em-dashes, in accordance with the definition you provide.

Comment: I'd rather use "which" than "that" in this; it feels like supplemental information and isn't necessary.